# one segue performing double time

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I have two segue for addition view controller . One segue i am using bar button from main storyboard to addition controller where there is a blank formate to be filled by user.second segue is from table view to additional view controller where data can be saved, deleted or updated. I used controll dragged in both the cases . In code for table view segue i am using code for didselectrow to pass on data from one controller to another .

Problem: on execution of second segue it ultimately performing but after showing first segue. I mean if i perform tableview segue , first blank format appears and self terminates to filled page . It appears to me first segue is being performed and then second 
I can share codes of required

Comment: It's unclear, but a common issue is that the segue is linked from a UITableViewCell to next UIViewController instead of doing from first UIViewController to next UIViewController. If you call yourself `performSegue()` by code in didSelectRow, it will trigger twice then, one with info, the other one without.

Comment: share some code to better understand your problem

Answer (score 0):

I have not quite clearly understood your question but try to use function **shouldPerformSegue** (see example below). It will help you to block or allow segues depending on conditions set by other parts of controller.

```
override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    var result = true
    if identifier == "EditItemSegue" && itemMoved! {
        itemMoved = false
        result = false
    }
    return result
}
```